# Detect New iOS 8.3 Emojis

Tags: ios, objective-c, emoji, ios8.3

I've run into a very bizarre bug on iOS versions below 8.3. Essentially what's happening is iOS 8.3 emojis are causing `UITextView`s inside `UITableViewCell`s to behave weirdly. I have a `UITableView` and as it's scrolled and the cells are recycled, any `UITextView`s that previously contained an iOS 8.3 emoji start displaying their contents very weirdly. The vertical spacing is weird, spacing between characters is weird, and some words become invisible.

To solve this, I'd like to replace all occurrences of 8.3 emojis with something else. Is there a way to detect only emojis specific to iOS 8.3?

Comment: Sure, if you have a list of which ones they are. Do you?

Comment: No, I've been having trouble finding a list like that. Every list I've found includes all emojis, not just the new iOS 8.3 ones.

Comment: Well, you could find a list of all the emojis from 8.2, then find a list of all the emojis from 8.3, and subtract... :)

Comment: Well Matt, you suggested exactly what I was hoping no one would suggest... :P I'll do the work and post the results here.